# How to query web server for existing text within a web page?

Tags: jquery, html, version

I have a page on a certain domain (let's call it domain1.com) which is checking for a version number.

Example: **1.0**

Then I have another domain (let's call it domain2.com) where there is another page.
On domain2.com, I manually update the version number by editing the text.
So say I update the number on domain2.com to **1.1**

I want the page on domain1.com, **on page load** to query domain2.com to see if the number is the same.

- If same, then the text next to it says, "**up to date!**".
- If different, then change the text next to it to say, "**update available!**".

So what is the best way to do this, and how do I do it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does the page have any other content besides the version number?

Comment: @Sam-Battat yes, but if it's easier I am fine with making ONLY the version number on a separate page of domain2.com

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript on your domain1.com page can only send AJAX requests to domain1.com, not to domain2.com (check "same origin policy", e.g. here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

However you can send the request to your domain1.com server, where some backend software does a AJAX call to domain2.com, the result can be transported to your browser as result of the AJAX call.

Comment: Yes, I just learned that javascript can't do cross domain. So do you have a solution?

Comment: Not a clean one. You probably want the chrome extension to work, without resorting to code on an external server, and I don't know what services chrome allows extension writers, I would need to study their docs.

Comment: No, I got it working myself but it's just slowing down the extension. SO I guess I'll never accept any answers on the question unless someone gives something new.

Comment: If you can live with newer browsers and you have some control over the servers then CORS might be a solution: http://enable-cors.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you can put a JavaScript file on **domain2** that is kept in sync with the version number, something like this perhaps:

```
window.domain2_version = "1.1";
```

then from **domain1** you can do this:

```
<script src='http://domain2.com/version_script.js'></script>
<script>
  if (myVersion == window.domain2_version) {
    // do whatever
  }
</script>
```

The code in the **domain1** page cannot look at the code inside the JavaScript file, but it can see the effects of the code after it runs.

Comment: @user2651403 did you check the browser console for errors?  Did you actually use "myVersion" or did you use a string that represents the version you actually want to check for?  I was just making up an example.

Comment: Please check the jsfiddle I posted the link to. I did not use myVersion anywhere else. How did you want me to use that? Am I supposed to write more code?

Comment: @user2651403 yes; the answer is about a technique for fetching information cross-domain. Your page in **domain1** would have to know what version it considers "up-to-date", or whatever it is that you want to check, and then make the appropriate comparison.

Comment: Ok I figured out I need to write a function for myVersion .. I tried to update the jsfiddle but it caused an error with jsfiddle so I'm going to try to find an alternative to jsfiddle.

Comment: ok I updated the code, jsfiddle isn't working right, but here is another site where I hosted the code to demo: http://jsbin.com/iKaWEFI/3/edit?html,js,output. Now the issue is that it is supposed to say Yes but instead it says No.

Comment: @user2651403 OK well you have to actually *call* your function: `if (myVersion() == window.domain2_version) ...`

Comment: I tried something different, still not working, still says No but supposed to say Yes: http://jsbin.com/iKaWEFI/5/edit

Comment: @user2651403 ?? you named the function "myVersion2", but when you call it you use the name "myVersion1".  You need to be looking at your browser's developer console, because it'll report those errors to you.

Comment: It seems the main problem with your answer is you forgot to give half of the code to put on domain1. You forgot to tell me what to do with myVersion. So until you give that I can't do anything with your code.

Comment: @user2651403 I didn't "forget"; I'm not here to write code for you. You asked a question about retrieving information from a different domain, and I provided one way to do that.

Comment: @user2651403 - As a caution, insulting people trying to help you doesn't get you very far here. Let's keep this constructive.

Comment: Useless answer, completely bad. If I had more points I would downvote.